# Hyperlink function to certain cell on another Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a hyperlink that goes to a certain cell on another Excel document. This is the formula that I have tried to accomplish this:

> =HYPERLINK("[C:\Blender\H) Blender Modelling Basics Fundementals\A) Blender Basics\Origins, Object transformations .xlsx]'1) ORIGINS'!C85",B89)

When clicked on, the hyperlink function opens the external worksheet `Origins, Object transformations.xlsx`, but does not go to cell `C85`.

Instead, it gives the message "Reference not valid".

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

#### Syntax

```
=HYPERLINK( " full_path_to_file # sheet_name ! cell_reference " )
```

<sup>(without the spaces)</sup>

- Sheet name and file name are seperated by `#`
- Cell reference and sheet name are seperated by `!`
- Cell reference can be a range, single cell or even a named range
- Special characters like `()[],` in your file path are no problem for Excel

#### Example

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Nixda\Desktop\Target.xlsx#Table2!B11")
```

<sup>Tested with two Excel 2013 files</sup>